# windows core iot dll

Tags: windows, dll, .net-core, windows-10-iot-core

I want to controll a robot arm with a raspberry pi running windows 10 iot. There is a dll to controll the arm. In the documentation of the dll it says that a .NET 2.0 framework is required. Is it possible to use the dll in my application for the windows core iot?

Comment: You could have a try to use .Net Core. [.NetCore](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core) And could you provide the name of the dll which controlls the arm?

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 10 IoT Core you create apps to do such things using the Universal Windows Platform (UWP) framework. This uses .Net Core. Not the full framework.

Check the latest version of the assemblies you require.

https://www.microsoft.com/net/core